Sharepoint: change column name in views
i have a list of 100 columns, 10k rows and i need to create 15 views.
I want to edit the column display name for some of the views.
i.e. column "Originator" is ok for view 1,2,3 and 6 but i want to have "Initiator" for the other views.
My brute-force idea is to create multiple columns with different names. But this would mean that i'll have repetitions (and even more columns... approx 122).
The list is not ready yet. I've just finished the query to extract the XLS that i'm going to use to create the list.
Any suggestion?

I searched the web...but could only find old answers (7 to 10 yrs ago). If i missed something, please point me in the right direction

There is no direct way to "change column header per view, without changing actual field title".
If you are willing to take many extra steps, you can dive into list view formatting and customize how view is rendered. That gives you absolute control on visual, but comes with great cost - you need to define everything. Example.

Thanks Kristaps, I'll give it a try for a single column and if the cost is too much, i'll give up.
